# Async and Backgroundworker combination

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I have following code in WPF, my problems are :

1. How to update my textbox with parallel task and backgroundworker ?. I know my mistake is writing `txtResult1.text` , `txtResult2.text`, `txtResult3.text` inside `worker_DoWork` events. But how to fix this ?
2. Do I need `ReadLineAsync` and `WriteLineAsync` for code ?

Here is my code:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        worker.DoWork +=worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(() =>
                    {  Task.Run(() => txtResult1.text = ReadCharacter("C:\\File 1.txt")); },
                    () =>
                    { Task.Run(()  => txtResult2.text = ReadCharacter("C:\\File 2.txt")); },
                    () =>
                    { Task.Run(()  => txtResult3.text = ReadCharacter("C:\\File 3.txt")); }
                    );

    }

    private string ReadCharacter(string inputFile)
    {
        string result; string TID;           
        using (StreamReader sr =new StreamReader(inputFile))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(string.Format("{0}--Out.txt", inputFile.Replace(".txt",""))))
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            TID = "Thread ID: "+ Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
            sb.AppendLine(TID);
            sb.AppendLine("T Start : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "." + 
                    DateTime.Now.Millisecond).ToString();
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                result = sr.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(result);
            };

            return
            sb.AppendLine("T Stop : "+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "." + 
                    DateTime.Now.Millisecond).ToString();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This is all rather a bad idea.  Threading buys you more cpu cores, not more hard disks.  Using threads to send the disk reader zipping back and forth between files is *very* detrimental to throughput.  How to update UI from a worker thread is already covered by thousands of questions.  Thanks, but we don't need another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your approach:

1. `Task.Run` doesn't buy you anything if you're already using `Parallel.Invoke`.
2. `Parallel` is the wrong solution if you want to do *concurrent I/O* - `Parallel` is for parallel CPU-bound operations.
3. `BackgroundWorker` is pretty much legacy at this point. I have a [blog series that shows how `Task.Run` is better than `BackgroundWorker`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html).

Also, as @HansPassnat pointed out, you almost certainly do *not* want concurrent disk access since that will usually slow you down considerably.

But if you really want to do it, I'd recommend an `async` approach:

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var progress = new Progress<string>(value => { txtResult1.Text = value; });
  await Task.WhenAll(ReadCharacterAsync("C:\\File 1.txt", progress),
      ReadCharacterAsync("C:\\File 2.txt", progress),
      ReadCharacterAsync("C:\\File 3.txt", progress));
  MessageBox.Show("Done");
}

private async Task ReadCharacterAsync(string inputFile, IProgress<string> progress)
{
    string result; string TID;
    using (var inFile = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 8192, useAsync: true))
    using (var outFile = new FileStream(string.Format("{0}--Out.txt", inputFile.Replace(".txt","")), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, 8192, useAsync: true))
    using (StreamReader sr =new StreamReader(inFile))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outFile))
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        TID = "Thread ID: "+ Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
        sb.AppendLine(TID);
        sb.AppendLine("T Start : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "." + 
                DateTime.Now.Millisecond).ToString();
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            result = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(result);
        };

        progress.Report(
        sb.AppendLine("T Stop : "+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "." + 
                DateTime.Now.Millisecond).ToString());
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in WPF you have to use Dispatcher for accessing controls from other threads:

```
 Parallel.Invoke(() =>
                {  Task.Run(() => this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
                   txtResult1.Text += ReadCharacter("C:\\File 2.txt")); },
                )
```

Comment: you can do it just with using Task.Factory.Startnew it is good for async work.

Comment: if you want more information you can check these articles: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx  there is no need for background worker anymore,we have TPL :)

Answer (score 0):

You must set the text boxes on the same thread that handled the event.  You can do this via a `Task`'s `.ContinueWith(...)` method or by using async/await in a method as shown below (or the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method as described in another solution):

```
private async Task GetDataAndSetTextBoxAsync( TextBox textBox, Func<char> dataMethod )
{
    var task = Task.StartNew( taskMethod );

    await task;

    // this will run on thread that called this method
    // in a WPF application
    textBox.Text = task.Result;
}
```

Usage:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var tasks = new Task[]
    {
        GetDataAndSetTextBoxAsync( txtResult1, () => ReadCharacter("C:\\File 1.txt") );
        GetDataAndSetTextBoxAsync( txtResult2, () => ReadCharacter("C:\\File 2.txt") );
        GetDataAndSetTextBoxAsync( txtResult3, () => ReadCharacter("C:\\File 3.txt") );
    };

    // uncomment below if you wish to wait for task completion
    // Task.WaitAll( tasks );
}
```